# Trying to kill Tomcat process but keeps getting recreated

Tags: tomcat

I was attempting to restart tomcat8 however i got the following warning:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I attempted to identify the process through a variety of methods found online including killing java and tomcat. Every time I kill the process when i check again another tomcat process has started. How would i go about killing the process at source. The following is output from

```
ps -ef | grep [t]omcat
```

I assume the second column is the PID but given there are so many i dont want to kill everything for fear of making it worse.

```
tomcat    4328 14814  0 09:48 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
tomcat    4329 14814  0 09:48 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto [t]omcat
root     13659   947  0 Oct01 ?        00:00:00 sshd: tomcat [priv]
tomcat   13707 13659  0 Oct01 ?        00:00:00 sshd: tomcat@pts/1
tomcat   13708 13707  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
root     13789 13728  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   13790 13789  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     13854 13803  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   13855 13854  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     13930 13868  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   13931 13930  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     14099 14049  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   14100 14099  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     14213 14151  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   14214 14213  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     14353 14284  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   14354 14353  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
tomcat   14620     1  1 Oct01 ?        00:11:59 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/lib/tomcat8/endorsed -classpath /var/lib/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/lib/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/var/lib/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat8/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     14721 14709  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   14722 14721  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root     14813 14736  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 su tomcat
tomcat   14814 14813  0 Oct01 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pid you need to "kill" is `14620` (the java process)

Warning : Depending on your exact setup other scripts might have a loop arround that pid.

Therefor did you try to stop tomcat with the normal shutdown/startup scripts?

In the tomcat `bin/` folder you might have f.e. shutdown.sh and/or startup.sh

This depends on the distribution ,tomcat version and how you installed tomcat though

Comment: Yes i tried to stop via the bin folder but when i attempt to restart I get the above messages about "Address Already in Use". When i kill this process i run ps -ef | grep [t]omcat again and its still there. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you use kill, just kill $PID, or do you use kill -9 $PID?

are you root user, do you have permission to kill this process?

Comment: I did a sudo pkill -9 $PID? Strangely I can now access sites on this server even though I havent attempted to restart it since. Strange. I will mark you as correct anyway as your identified the java process. Thanks.